# Capture Photo and store to internal storage android

Tags: android

I want to select image from camera or file and use it for crop activity.So i created a file in external storage and pass it to camera activity it works successfully.But when i try to create file in internal storage and pass it,not working.

```
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
                    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                               // File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

                                  File f = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                            } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                            } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Elaborate on "not working." What doesn't work specifically? Are you getting an error?

Comment: After capturing image when i click OK button it not respond,while using externalstoragedirectory works properly by starting croping activity

Answer (score 0):

Third-party camera apps cannot write to locations in your app's [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getFilesDir()`), as they do not have access to it.

You are welcome to try using something like `FileProvider` to expose a location on internal storage via a `content://` `Uri`, and try that, but I suspect that many camera apps will not expect such `Uri` values.

The only way I know of that definitely would allow you to take a picture to internal storage would be to use the camera APIs and take the picture yourself, and that is not easy.

Comment: I am not using third party camera app.Just using phone camera function
MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: @LalitJadiya: That *is* a third-party camera app. You are not taking the picture in your own app using the camera APIs (e.g., `android.hardware.camera2.*`). You are asking another app to take the picture on your behalf. There are thousands of Android device models, with hundreds of built-in camera apps between them (plus others that users can install), and any of them could be what handle your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`.

Comment: What if device doesnt have externalstorage

Comment: @LalitJadiya: Then you can't take a picture, unless the `FileProvider` approach happens to work (I have never tried that). Since virtually all Android devices have [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), this will only affect a small number of users. Your bigger problem is that third-party camera apps' implementation of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` sometimes is buggy (e.g., ignoring `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, never returning control to your app).